# Reference to sidenote

Tags: cross-referencing, sidenotes

I am trying to create a scholia book document using the **sidenotes** package.

When I refer to the second sidenote the text is "sidenote 1.1.2" but for the first sidenote what appears is "sidenote 1.1". How to fix this bug?

Here is a compact working code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}

 \usepackage{sidenotes}

 \usepackage[outer=7cm]{geometry}

 \usepackage{chngcntr}
 \counterwithin{sidenote}{section}
 \makeatletter
 \renewcommand{\thesidenote}{\@arabic{\numexpr\value{chapter}\relax}.\@arabic{\numexpr\value{section}\relax}.\@arabic{\numexpr\value{sidenote}+1\relax}}
 \makeatother


 \begin{document}

 \chapter{Example}

 \section{Cake}

 This is an example.\sidenote{First sidenote.\label{first}} \\
 This is second\sidenote{Second sidenote.\label{second}} \\
 More text... \\
     ...
   ... \\
 Then I refer to sidenote \ref{first} and then to sidenote \ref{second}.

 \end{document}
```

The code compiles but the last sentence appers as

> Then I refer to sidenote 1.1 and then to sidenote 1.1.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `sidenotes` package increases the `sidenote` counter at the end, so the referencees are only set up after the sidenote already ended. This can be fixed by changing `\sidenotetext` to do `\refstepcounter` before setting the sidenote:

```
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand \sidenotetext { o o +m }
{
  \IfNoValueOrEmptyTF{#1}
    {
      \refstepcounter{sidenote}
      \@sidenotes@placemarginal{#2}{\textsuperscript{\thesidenote}{}~#3}
    }
    {
      \@sidenotes@placemarginal{#2}{\textsuperscript{#1}~#3}
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother
```

Then `\sidenote` has to be changed too to avoid printing the wrong number in the text: In the original code the mark is set first(with the old counter value), we want to add the note (and increase the counter) first:

```
\RenewDocumentCommand \sidenote { o o +m }
{
  \@sidenotes@multichecker
  \sidenotetext[#1][#2]{#3}
  \sidenotemark[#1]
  \@sidenotes@multimarker
}
```

This also replaces your `\renewcommand\thesidenote`, so we get

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{sidenotes}

\usepackage[outer=7cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{sidenote}{section}
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand \sidenote { o o +m }
{
  \@sidenotes@multichecker
  \sidenotetext[#1][#2]{#3}
  \sidenotemark[#1]
  \@sidenotes@multimarker
}
\RenewDocumentCommand \sidenotetext { o o +m }
{
  \IfNoValueOrEmptyTF{#1}
    {
      \refstepcounter{sidenote}
      \@sidenotes@placemarginal{#2}{\textsuperscript{\thesidenote}{}~#3}
    }
    {
      \@sidenotes@placemarginal{#2}{\textsuperscript{#1}~#3}
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter{Example}

\section{Cake}

This is an example.\sidenote{First sidenote.\label{first}} \\
This is second\sidenote{Second sidenote.\label{second}} \\
More text... \\
    ...
  ... \\
Then I refer to sidenote \ref{first} and then to sidenote \ref{second}.

\end{document}
```

[image]